# Pythonic way of checking for 0 in if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

In coding a primality tester, I came across an interesting thought. When you want to do something if the result of an operation turns out to be `0`, which is the better ('pythonic') way of tackling it?

```
# option A - comparison
if a % b == 0:
    print('a is divisible by b')

# option B - is operator
if a % b is 0:
    print('a is divisible by b')

# option C - boolean not
if not a % b:
    print('a is divisible by b')
```

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that comparisons to singletons like `None` should be done with the `is` operator. It also says that checking for empty sequences should use `not`, and not to compare boolean values with `==` or `is`. However, it doesn't mention anything about checking for a `0` as a result.

So which option should I use?

Comment: I prefer option C, though I don't know whether it is (more) Pythonic

Comment: I prefer A, more readable. Looking at Python 3.3 source code, I count 362 times the string " == 0:", and never " is 0:". More difficult to check automatically for option C, but I suspect option A is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing against `0` is (imo) best done by testing against `0`. This also indicates that there might be other values than just `0` and `1`.

If the called function really only returns `0` on success and `1` on fail to say `Yes/No`, `Success/Failure`, `True/False`, etc., then I think the function is the problem and should (if applicable) be fixed to return `True` and `False` instead.

Comment: `0`and `1` (or another int) as return values are very common when executing external programs, e.g., `subprocess.call` has exactly these return values.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz: Be that as it may, it's nice to be explicit wherever possible, especially if you have control over the return values. Returning `True` or `False` tells whoever calls the function that it *only* returns 2 values. 0 and 1 are a bit more ambiguous.

Comment: Sure, I didn't want to say "use 1 and 0". I literally hate statements like `while 1:`. We're in the 21st century, and we have `bool`-type. Just wanted to point out that there are situations were the return values are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

just personal : I prefer the `not a % b` way because it seems to be highly readable. But now, to lower the confusion level in the code, I will use the `== 0`, as it express what you expect to test exactly in a more accurate way. It's the "care for debug" approach.

Answer (score 1):

0 isn't guaranteed to be a singleton so don't use `is` to test against it: currently C Python re-uses small integers so there is probably only one `int` with the value 0 plus a `long` if you're still on Python 2.x, and any number of float zeroes not to mention False which all compare equal to 0. Some earlier versions of Python, before it got a separate bool type used a different int zero for the result of comparisons.

Use either `==` (which would be my preference) or just the `not`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

A and C are both valid and very pythonic.

B is not, because

1. `0` semantically is not a singleton (it is in cPython, but that is an implementation detail).
2. It will not work with float `a` or `b`.
3. It is actually possible that this will not work in some other implementation of Python.